# What is the best way to add insulation to an uninsulated 1950's house?

Tags: insulation, old-house, california

We are in the process of closing on a 1950s house (1 story, 1100sq ft, 2B/1ba) in southern california. It has not been renovated (old windows, no insulation anywhere) but in decent conditions.

I am trying to understand how insulating attic and crawl space can help us with energy efficiency and general comfort.

Will adding something like R30 fiberglass in the attic help with temp control? Is it a DIY project? Will adding some sort of insulation under the floor help with keeping floors reasonable temp in winter and preserve cold air inside during summer?

[image: attic and crawl space photos]

Comment: You're asking multiple questions, one of which is highly subjective, and the rest of which are quite broad. (Of _course_ insulation helps.) Please see [ask] and take the [tour], then revise to ask a single, specific question.

Comment: What color is the roof?  How do you feel about that color?

Comment: Standard advice: contact your local utility company to see if they offer free energy efficiency surveys, which often also qualify for subsidized work to implement the recommendations of their contractors. I had my place in NA air-sealed and  several feet of insulation blown into the attic for a cost to me of $800; admittedly that was a decade ago but I don't think I could have done it cheaper by doing it myself.

Answer (score 4):

> Will adding something like R30 fiberglass in the attic help with temp control?

Absolutely, because "...about [25% of the heat in an uninsulated house escapes through the roof](https://www.energy.gov/energysaver/where-insulate-home)." Energy.gov recommends [attic insulation](https://www.hortmag.com/smart-gardening/soil-temperature-is-critical-to-garden-plants) as the first step for improving home energy efficiency.

You can get an idea on how much energy savings you would look at by visiting [EnergyStar's Methodology for estimating Energy Savings page](https://www.energystar.gov/campaign/seal_insulate/methodology).

> Is it a DIY project?

Yes.

Insulation is commonly added to homes without hiring a contractor. Note that you will need access to your attic- normally through your attic accessway in your ceiling.

Rolls of batting tend to be the lowest cost per square foot, but tend to take more effort (as it needs to be cut and positioned in your attic).

A much easier option than batting is to use blown cellulose insulation. The equipment is frequently available at affordable prices to rent. Most manufacturers offer DIY guides [such as this site](https://www.greenfiber.com/homeowners).

> Will adding some sort of insulation under the floor help with keeping
> floors reasonable temp in winter and preserve cold air inside during
> summer?

Yes, adding insulation will help- but not as much as wall and attic insulation.

Common methods of insulating the floor is through spray foam (costly), rigid foam with spray foam (moderate cost) or batting insulation.

If you add batting insulation to the bottom of your floor, you will need to consider how to prevent moisture from getting trapped between the insulation and your floor. "...batting insulation had [20% higher moisture content](https://www.lsuagcenter.com/nr/rdonlyres/d33f711d-dc4b-4e4c-9ed6-a97dce9db026/79805/pub3187insulatingraisedfloorslowres.pdf) than other insulation methods."

How much efficiency you gain depends on the airflow underneath your home, and the temperature of your crawl space vs the outside temp. In the winter, the ground tends to hold heat [air tends to be much colder](https://www.hortmag.com/smart-gardening/soil-temperature-is-critical-to-garden-plants).

One final thought: note that many energy guides suggest focusing on air sealing first, then insulation second. This is because air sealing tends to have a [better impact against energy loss](https://asiri-designs.com/resources-1/f/insulation-vs-air-tightness---which-is-more-important?blogcategory=Remodeling).

Answer (score 1):

The other answers have your main question covered.  Yes, any insulation is better than no insulation, and yes, you can do it yourself.

I'll add some additional information - some of this may be considered opinion (hopefully at least *informed* opinion), since I have lived in a SoCal house of very similar age and construction.

I would advise using fiberglass batt insulation on the attic "floor" instead of blown cellulose.  I know blown-in insulation is cheap, easy, and plentiful, but the following makes batt more attractive:

- If it still has 60-70 year old electrical and plumbing, your house is likely going to need new wiring and/or piping in the near future.  If you laid fiberglass batt between the ceiling joists, you can fold it back for easy access to the top plates of your walls, do your work, and lay it back without issue.  Doing the same with blown insulation is *possible*, but takes much more effort and time.
- If you have any storage or equipment to maintain in the attic space, fiberglass is a lot nicer to be around than cellulose.  Fiberglass batt doesn't become airborne dust as easily.
- Cellulose, being a recycled paper derivative, will retain some moisture.  If you are near the coast, that could become an issue.

I would also look into adding radiant barrier (essentially fancy aluminum foil boards) to the underside of the roof decking.  That will help keep the attic temperatures down, which is essential if you have HVAC ducting or water piping in the attic.  In Southern CA, you're going to spend more of the year trying to keep heat *out* vs keeping it in.

Finally, there are lots of local contractors who will shoot the whole thing with spray foam.  I have no experience with that, so I can't really comment, but it is an option.

Comment: Radiant barrier can make a big difference, but you also want to make sure you've got proper airflow along the roof underside so you don't cook the roof and reduce its life. A soffit vents/ridge vent system is common and usually straightforward to add if you don't have one.

Comment: "radiant barrier" - our plan is to use radiant barrier OSB when changing the roof (it is 30 y old)

Answer (score 0):

R-30 batt insulation will definitely help with temperature control in the attic but R-38 would be even better since you have no insulation in there at all.

As far as the crawl space, 6" R-19 batts between the joists would further help. Depending on the actual climate, foam panels on the crawl space walls could further improve moisture control. This might be considered a DIY project if you're comfortable on ladders for the attic and crawling around and on you back for the crawl space. You might want to check with some local suppliers for some input on your specific area.

Answer (score 0):

For the attic, as the other said, either blown insulation or batts. If you use batts they must be cut to size to fit between the rafters, and cutting batts while crawling in an attic gets tiring very quickly. Whereas with blown insulation, you just spray and it fills every nook and cranny. It's MUCH easier and it has better performance because it doesn't leave any gaps. Another advantage of blown insulation is you don't have to bring all the material up on the ladder, the blower does it.

You should do all the work you'll need to do in the attic before insulating: ventilation, pipes, electricity, etc.

Besides insulation, you should also consider drafts.

For example, in the attic, check the floor, which is also the ceiling of the living space below. Look for holes around wood beams, slots and cracks between boards, etc that would let air from the living space escape into the attic. It's not possible to install "house wrap" membrane because of the rafters, but if you find any holes you can plug them with canned foam or other suitable materials.

Blown cellulose is much tighter than rockwool or fiberglass so it is more airtight, which is good to prevent drafts. However the cellulose "grains" are also much smaller, so if you have gaps the insulation may fall through and make a lot of dust in the living space. So it's a bit of a compromise, you have to check the state of things in your attic. Cellulose is also messy to blow in on an whole another level, it really makes tons of dust.

Spray foam is ideal in theory, it's an excellent insulator, vapor barrier, and it's airtight, all in one, but it has disadvantages... not the least of which is its flammability. It's rigid, once it's done it's done, and if you need to install a new wire, good luck. Whereas with blown insulation you can use the leaf rake from the garden, push it to the side a bit, and get to work. And if the installers screw up the mix, the house will stink like rotting fish forever (but that's pretty rare).

The attic should be well ventilated, I see a window so that's fine. If you can open it in the summer to vent the hot air, that's better. The window and any other openings to the outside need a wire mesh to keep rodents and other animals out, as some of them love to nest in insulation materials and make a mess.

Here's my attic after blowing fiberglass:

[image]

It's absolutely doable DIY. The shop where we bought the insulation lent us the blowing machine (you can also rent one). You need a long enough pipe, and someone on the ground to load the material into the machine. With 3-4 people it'll be done in the afternoon. I put 40cm thick, once you got the machine going it makes no sense to skimp on the material, and it's pretty cheap. The longest bit is to find and plug all the holes, and/or install vapor barrier. Make sure you read your local code about the chimney, usually you'll have to build a box to keep the insulation away from it.

If you use fiberglass you need a good N95 respirator, or better 3M 7502 with P100 pancake filters. If you use cellulose, you need a full face mask.

Before you insulate, it's also a good time to:

- Spend time in the attic when it rains and look for leaks
- Spray some bug/termite repellant on the wood structure. I didn't want to breathe the stuff so I had professionals do it.